# Find those people that have type a, but not b. Using minus equivalent

Tags: mysql

Let's say for a table Person, I have the relations as follows:

Person: (person,type)

There are only two types: a or b
Person can have multiple types

Question: Find those people that have type a, but not b.

For example:

```
Person   type
mary     a
mary     b
steve    a
bob      a
```

I want just this

```
Person
steve
bob
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT person FROM Person
    where type = 'a'

MINUS

SELECT person FROM Person
    where type = 'b'
```

MYSQL doesn't support MINUS or EXCEPT. The alternatives I'm looking up keep giving me an error. How would I do this without MINUS or EXCEPT?

Comment: Which "alternatives"?

Comment: Why not just change your query? `SELECT person FROM Person WHERE type != 'b'` … You say a person can have multiple types, so use a string match?

Comment: "Find those people that have type a, but not b.". A person could have both types that way wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternative to the difference operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve the expected results.

You can use the `not exists` operator (or use `not in` instead):

```
SELECT person FROM Person
where type = 'a'
    and not exists (select 1 from Person p2 where p2.type<>'a' and p2.person=Person.person)
```

You can also do it via a self join:

```
SELECT p1.person FROM Person p1
LEFT JOIN Person p2 on p1.person=p2.person and p2.type<>'a'
where p1.type = 'a' and p2.person is null
```

It is very important to place the `p2.type<>'a'` criterion into the join condition, this way it only applies to the p2 table, not the entire resultset.